# Finding the Unicode for the key pressed in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, input, unicode, keyboard

How can one determine the Unicode of the key pressed in javascript?

I googled on this and most of the results only answer as to how to find the keyCode. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `var code = e.keyCode || e.which;`

Comment: @LightStyle: but that gives us the keyCode and not the Unicode. For example the Unicode for 'ಅ' would be 0C85 and the keyCode would be 65!

Comment: Try executing this: `'ಅ'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)`, it will print `"C85"`. If the problem is of the keyboard, the best solution IMHO is to retrieve the char from the keycode and then get its original base-16 code with that little snippet. But it's weird

Comment: The `e.which` event property of `onkeypress` gives you an Unicode.  `e.which` in `onkeydown` and `keyup` handlers gives a code of the pressed key.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, but @LightStyle:I want to find the Unicode of the key last pressed. In other words, I do not know what was pressed (in this case 'ಅ')

Comment: As @Teemu suggested, use the `e.which` captured during `onkeypress` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, as per [DOM3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/), you should use the `key` property of an event object. In practice, it doesn’t work, except in sufficiently new versions of IE.

The practical approach is to use the `which` property or the `charCode` property, even though the DOM3 Events draft frowns upon them:

> Browser support for keyboards has traditionally relied on three ad-hoc
>   attributes, `keyCode`, `charCode`, and `which`.
>
> All three of these attributes return a numerical code that represents
>   some aspect of the key pressed: `keyCode` is an index of the key itself.
>   `charCode` is the ASCII value of the character keys. `which` is the
>   character value where available and otherwise the key index. The
>   values for these attributes, and the availability of the attribute, is
>   inconsistent across platforms, keyboard languages and layouts, user
>   agents, versions, and even event types.

In reality, `charCode` returns the Unicode value (code number).

The following simple code can be used to test the functionality (it just echoes the character number in an element on the page):

```
<style>
#o { border: solid black 1px; }
</style>
<input id=i>
<div id=o></div>
<script>
document.getElementById('i').onkeypress = function (e) {
  var ev = e || window.event;
  document.getElementById('o').innerHTML += 
    ev.charCode + ' '; 
}
</script>
```

This seems to work in modern browsers, including IE 9 and newer. For older browsers, you may need to try to do something with `keyCode` based on a guess of the keyboard mapping.